# lookup tables for one to one relationship only?

Tags: php, mysql, database-design, entity-relationship, lookup-tables

Is it a good practice to use the **lookup** table to store **1:1 relationship** only between tables?

For instance

`system` table

```
system_id
name
etc
```

`path` table

```
path_id
value
```

the **lookup** table - `system_has_path` table,

```
system_id
path_id
```

I have **other tables** to link up with the `path` table, for instance,

`page` table,

```
page_id
title
etc
```

the **lookup** table of `page_has_path`,

```
page_id
path_id
```

a `page` item/ row or a `system` item/row will always has **one path per row** only. Of course **sometimes** they don't have any path, that's why I want to separate path into a standalone table.

The reason I use lookup tables for them is that I don't want the store FK in `path` table and end up like this,

```
path_id   value   page_id   system_id    post_id    news_id
1         a.php   1         NULL         NULL       NULL
2         b.php   NULL      1            NULL       NULL
3         c.php   NULL      2            NULL       NULL
```

it looks pretty ugly with lots of `NULL` or `empty` fields.

or if you have other better solutions/ practice?

Comment: Just a note, whatever you decide you may want to use Foreign Key constraints inside your database to ensure data integrity between tables. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are doing all of this just to prevent NULL values in your path_id columns, then I say, don't worry about the NULL values.

However, if you don't mind the complexity for the sake of normalization, and want to keep path in its own table, but don't want junction tables for 1 to 1 relationships, then consider the following approach.

Where the primary key is `(id, path_type)`:

```
path table
----------------
id      path_type    value
1       page         a.php
1       system       b.php
2       system       c.php
```

Here's the query for that:

```
SELECT *
FROM page
LEFT JOIN path
  ON path.id = page.page_id AND path.path_type = 'page'
```

Comment: thanks for this idea. but i am a bit confused as you have two repeated primary key which is id 1 - why is that?

Comment: The primary key is over both fields, id and path_type, so there is no duplicate primary key. Where path_type is page, id points to a page record, and where path_type is system, id points to a system record.

Comment: @Marcus: How do you enforce integrity with this approach? How do you disallow a row with `(id, path_type)` of `(7, page)` be inserted when there is no `page` with `id=7` ?

Answer (score 2):

Opposite to other answers, yes, this is the (most) normalized approach. Advantages:

- You don't have Nulls in your columns.
- If you later want to add a Foreign Key reference from another table to `system_has_path` (to systems that have path and not to any system) or to `page_has_path`, you can do it easily, without changing your existing tables.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see any problem on using a single table (even with lots of `NULL` values inside). That approach will save you from having to add an extra `JOIN` to your `SELECT` queries.

You may use multiple lookup tables, but then use a `UNIQUE` index on both FK columns to prevent duplicates (since you state your relationships are all one-to-one).

Answer (score -1):

Presumably, your posts table (for example) is:

```
posts(id, path_id, etc..)
```

Why aren't u using that?